# Redux thunk not fireing

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have been searching countless hours the last days trying to solve it on my own, but to no avail... I have a really simple thunk but the actual dispatch is never called...

This is the action creator:

```
const startSurvey = () => {
  console.log("inside startSurvey thunk")
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log("inside startSurvey thunk func")
  }
}
```

The first log I can see, never the second one. I have my store properly setup (I think)

```
export const configureStore = (onComplete: ?() => void) => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it! I was calling the action creator by a simple onPress handler on a button instead of dispatching it! What a rookie mistake, but it took me hours and hours until @awestroke on discords helped me!